# How to install user PFX certificate

Tags: certificates

I need to install a PFX certificate into some analog of personal certificates store in Windows.

Does a personal certificate store exist in Ubuntu?
If it does, how can I install the PFX certificate into it?

Comment: https://www.helloitsliam.com/2016/03/30/installing-certificate-pfx-into-debian-linux/ should be the same for Ubuntu.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, they install certificates into ca-certificates store. It is Trusted Root Certification Authorities analog? What about personal certificates? Or in Ubuntu all certificates are stored in ca-certificates?